# Stored procedure logic for select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_types
    @type varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @products table(productId int)

    IF @type = 'Merchandise'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @products
            SELECT productId
            FROM dbo.product
            WHERE type = @type
    END
    ELSE IF @type = 'Electronics'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @products
            SELECT productId
            FROM dbo.product
            WHERE type = @type
    END
    ELSE IF @type = 'Home'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @products
            SELECT productId
            FROM dbo.product
            WHERE type = @type
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @products
            SELECT productId
            FROM dbo.product
            WHERE type = @type
    END

    /* here we have logic to convert all the productids in the @products table into an XML format
    <products>
      <productId>1</productId>
      <productId>2</productId>
    ....
    ....
    ....
      <productId>100</productId>
    </products>
    */

    /* after we get the XML string, it is passed to another procedure to print out details about the products */
    EXEC sp_products_list @xml = @productXml

END /* procedure ends here */
```

Here's the `sp_products_list` procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_products_list
    @xml XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @products TABLE (productId int)

    INSERT INTO @products
        SELECT @xml.value('productId','int')
        FROM @xml.nodes('products')

    /* Select statement */
    SELECT
        a.productId, a.productName, 
        b.productRegion, b.ProductQuantity, 
        c.productSupplier
    FROM
        products a
    JOIN 
        productRegion b ON a.productid = b.productid
    JOIN 
        productSupplier c ON c.productRegion = b.productRegion
    WHERE 
        a.productId IN (SELECT productId FROM @products)

END /* procedure end */
```

The `sp_products_list` is called by many other procedures other than the `sp_types` procedure. I have a requirement wherein when I pass a type of 'Merchandise' to the `sp_types` procedure, then I need some additional columns like `productSupplierRegion`, `productSupplierCount` etc. displayed.

But for the rest of the types, I only need to display what the select statement in the `sp_products_list` procedure currently displays.

If I simply add the columns that I need to the select statement in the current `sp_products_list` procedure then they will be displayed for any type that is passed to the `sp_types` procedures and that is not what I want.

My solution: one of the solutions I could think of was receiving a @type variable as an input in the `sp_products_list` procedure and having an if-else statement for the select statement. If the type of 'Merchandise' is passed in then display the select with additional columns otherwise display the regular columns.

The problem I might face in the future with this approach is what if we want to add different types of columns for different `@type` variables that are passed in. In that case, I'll have to have to do multiple if-else statements for each type. I was planning on using dynamic SQL but my idea was shot down since my team is not a huge fan of dynamic SQL.

Now I'm trying to find a robust solution for this problem that might work in any scenario. Any thoughts or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: As a rule a stored procedure shouldn't return results that have differing sets of columns, data types, number of result sets, ... depending on input parameters, time of month, disk capacity, ... . Sometimes it makes sense, but rarely. It requires that the application consuming the data can determine what to do with the resulting pile'o'bits in a reasonable way. Aside: It appears that all of the `if`/`then` code to handle values of `@type` do exactly the same thing for expected values, but handle unexpected values the same way. What aren't you telling us?

Comment: As per your requirement in the future, you have multiple types and each type required a different column list, then you should store type and column details in one table and fetch column details based on the type, and put them on a select statement. no, any if else statement required.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Side point: I would suggest you use table types to pass data between store procedures, this is likely much more efficient than XML. Although you could use XML for your current problem: extra columns which are only applicable some of the time, but you would have this as an XML column on your table type, not as a whole blob of every single row together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you rewrite `sp_products_list` as a table-valued function, then you can just join it with any extra columns you need

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.products_list ( @productId int )
RETURNS TABLE    
AS RETURN

    SELECT
        p.productId, p.productName, 
        pr.productRegion, pr.ProductQuantity, 
        ps.productSupplier
    FROM
        products p
    JOIN 
        productRegion pr ON p.productid = pr.productid
    JOIN 
        productSupplier ps ON ps.productRegion = pr.productRegion
    WHERE 
        p.productId = @productId;

GO
```

Then you simply use that function in each of the procedures. For example.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductByType
    @type varchar(100)
AS

    IF @type = 'Merchandise'
    BEGIN
        SELECT pl.*, p.OtherColumns, t.OtherTablesColumns
            FROM dbo.product p
            CROSS APPLY dbo.products_list (p.productId) pl
            LEFT JOIN OtherTable t ON SomeCondition
            WHERE p.type = @type;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT pl.*
            FROM dbo.product p
            CROSS APPLY dbo.products_list (p.productId) pl
            WHERE p.type = @type;
    END;
```

---

You may find it more performant to push the `@type` selection into the function also. Then you can simply do

```sql
SELECT pl.*
FROM dbo.products_list_by_type (@type) pl
```

The server will remove any columns that are not needed from the query plan.

Comment: Thank you so much! What if my result set has 100k rows? If I use a TVF won't it affect the performance since the function call has to be made for every single row?

Comment: No, an *inline* Table Valued function (a single `AS RETURN SELECT` like this one) is compiled into the outer query similarly to a view. As I say at the end, you may find better performance if you push the `@type` condition into the function, selecting all the columns you will ever need. The server will prune unnecessary columns from the final query plan. Either way performance will certainly be better than what you have already. I hope your indexing is good: you need an index on `type`